# The density function of the sum of n independent uniformly distributed random variable on $(-1,1)$ is supported on $[-n,n]$

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution, density-function

This question arose from the statement after **Exercise 3.3.6** of **Durrett's probability**.

> Exercise 3.3.6: Show that if $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ are independent uniformly distributed on $(-1,1)$, then for $n\geq 2$, $X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$ has density function $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}(\sin t/t)^{n}\cos(tx)dt.$$

I proved this exercise using the inversion formula in the case of integrable characteristic function and the fact that $\sin t/t$ is an even function.

But right after this exercise, **Durrett** said:

> Although it is not obvious from the formula, $f$ is a polynomial in each interval $(k, k+1)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and vanishes on $[-n,n]^{c}$.

I tried to prove this statement but I did not know where to begin, since as **Durrett** said, it is not obvious from the formula above, then what should I do?

I may need some answer with a little bit details since I really don't know what to do now.

Thank you!

Comment: The support part is clear.

Comment: Are you being asked to deduce this from this representation, or is the remark a "fun fact"? There are other approaches, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/619552/215011

Comment: @copper.hat Yes Durrett, I will edit right away.

Comment: @copper.hat why is the support part clear?

Comment: @grand_chat I don't know, Durrett did not say I should deduce this from the representation..

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: If each $X_k(\omega) \in (-1,1)$ then $\sum_k X_k(\omega) \in (-n,n)$, hence taking closure we get the support. The integral has a Chebyshev look to it...

Comment: @copper.hat okay I will take a look at Chebyshev.. and I am sorry for another dumb question... I understand that $\sum_{k}X_{k}\in (-n,n)$, and thus density function must be $0$ outside this region since we have uniform distribution, but why did you take closure? why would we need to include $-n$ and $n$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: It is just a matter of definition. Usually the support is a closed set. Some folks define the support as the smallest closed set $C$ such that $P[X \in C] = 1$. However, it is not entirely clear what smallest means to me in this context such that the result is measurable.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: Don't take my Chebyshev  too seriously... I just made the connection between trigonometric functions and polynomials without thinking it through in any depth.

Comment: @copper.hat would you like to answer this post so that I can give you upvote and approve it? :)

Comment: @copper.hat and at the same time.. I don't quite follow your trigonometric function connection.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: I haven't solved it. If I have time I will try later :-).

Comment: @copper.hat no problem, I will also head for this direction. Thank you!

Comment: Something similar to this is known as the Irwin Hall distribution.

Comment: I suspect a Fourier transform/Parseval's theorem approach might work.

Comment: @copper.hat but that's a integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$

Comment: Fourier transform, not series. I will look later when I finish work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get time, but I think it is straightforward using the Fourier transform. The only trick is to deal with the fact that for $n=1$ the $\operatorname{sinc}$ part is not integrable, but the Plancheral transform comes to the rescue. Will add it I get a chance tomorrow. To show the result amounts to showing that the convolution of $\operatorname{rect}$ functions ends up with a polynomial in the prescribed intervals.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh! Sorry for the late reply, I've been working on my homework.. I will also try Fourier transform after I finished my assignments... Thank you!

Comment: I added a rather long winded answer. It is also possible to do this without dragging in the Plancherel transform, by explicitly establishing the result for $n=2,3$ and using induction from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to show that $f$ is the rectangle function convolved with itself, and then to show that the convolution can be expressed as a polynomial on each $(k,k+1)$.

Let $\operatorname{sinc}x = { \sin x \over x}$, and use
$\hat{g}(\omega) =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$ to denote the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function $g$. If $\hat{g}$ is also $L^1$, the inversion theorem (Rudin, "Real and complex analysis", Theorem 9.11, note his measure normalisation to symmetrise the formula) gives
$g(t) = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{g}(\omega) e^{i\omega t} d\omega$
(interpreted in an ae. sense).

Let $r = 1_{[-1,1]}$, the symmetric rectangle function. It is straightforward to see that $\hat{r} = 2 \operatorname{sinc}$.

Note that since $\operatorname{sinc}$ is even, $f(t) = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ( \operatorname{sinc} \omega)^n e^{i\omega t} d\omega = {1 \over 2^{n+1} \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{r}^n(\omega) e^{i\omega t} d\omega$, which suggests that the Fourier transform (or its inverse) and convolution might be a productive approach.

In particular, it suggests that ${1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{r}^n(\omega) e^{i\omega t} d\omega = (\underbrace{r * r *\cdots * r }_{n\text{ times}})(t)$.

A catch is that $\operatorname{sinc}$ is not an $L^1$ function so the classic inversion theorem does not apply. (Note that this is only an issue for $n=1$, but I need the $n=1$ case for the next step.)

However, since $\operatorname{sinc}$ is $L^2$ we can use the Plancherel transform (denote by ${\cal P}$). If $a,b$ are $L^2$ and $a * b$ is $L^2$ then the Parseval formula can be used to show that ${\cal P}(a * b) = {\cal P}(a) \cdot {\cal P}(b)$.

Since $r$, $r * r$, etc., are $L^2$ and $\hat{r} = 2 \operatorname{sinc}$,
we have ${\cal P}(r) = 2 \operatorname{sinc}$, and so
${\cal P} (r * r * \cdots * r) = \hat{r}^n = 2^n \operatorname{sinc}^n$.
In particular, $f(t) = {1 \over 2^n} (r * r * \cdots * r))(t)$. Note that the
equality is in an $L^2$ sense.

For $n \ge 2$, all
functions involved are $L^1 \cap L^2$, so the Plancherel transform and the usual Fourier transform are the same, and since $f$ and $r * r * \cdots * r$ are both continuous, we have $f(t) = {1 \over 2^n} (r * r * \cdots * r)(t)$ everywhere.

(Thanks to Ted Shifrin who helped clarify some confusion I was having regarding convolution with the Plancherel transform. See p.110 of Fourier Transforms by Bochner & Chandrasekharan.)

Finally, note that $ r$ is constant (hence a polynomial) on each $(k,k+1)$. So, suppose that $g = r * r * \cdots * r$ is expressible as a polynomial on each $(k,k+1)$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
(r * g)(t) &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty r(t-s)g(s) ds \\
&=& \int_{t-1}^{t+1} g(s)ds \\
&=& \int_{t-1}^k g(s)ds + \int_k^{k+1} g(s)ds + \int_{k+1}^{t+1} g(s)ds
\end{eqnarray}
Since $g$ can be expressed as a polynomial on $(k-1,k)$ and $(k+1,k+2)$, it follows
that $r*g$ is expressible as a polynomial on $(k,k+1)$.

Comment: wow. You are brilliant, thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid not, but thank you anyway :-).